# How to display blue arrow for direction with Google Maps SDK in iOS?

Tags: google-maps

When launching Google Maps in iOS, the App will display a blue dot for my location and a blue arrow for direction I faced.
Is it possible to display the blue arrow with Google Maps SDK in iOS ?
If SDK does not provide this function, is there any way to implement it by myself ?

Answer (score 1):

I've spent a good amount of time researching this and the simple answer is no. I've combed through every page of the google maps iOS sdk documentation and have found nothing on user location direction. I have tried laying an arrow image on top of the mapView, but the problem is that the user dot does not always stay in the exact center, and there is no way to reference the location of the dot within the mapView. It seems that this is one feature that Google is keeping to themselves for some reason :(